# Trying to input values into a 2d array and print it, code not running

Tags: java

Code not running??

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Array2dNightPractice
{
    int[][] studentmarks;
    studentmarks = new int[3][3];

    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter 9 integers");

    for(int row = 0;row<3;row++){
        for(int col=0;col<3;col++){
            studentmarks[row][col] = kb.nextInt();
        }
    }

    for(int row = 0; row < 3; row++) {
        for(int col = 0; col < 4; col++) {
            System.out.print(studentmarks[row][col] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the error?? Please elaborate your question a little bit.

Comment: And this `for(int col = 0; col < 4; col++)` probably gives you an error since there are only 3 indices. There is no `studentmarks[3][4]`. It should *obviously* be `for(int col = 0; col < 3; col++)`.

Comment: You should see index out of range error? Are you see that?

Comment: @rotgers That was it! Thank you, I had 4 instead of 3.

Comment: Nice, please accept the answer below. It is an even more foolproof method.

Comment: @user7790438 yep! Sorry but thank you!

Comment: @rotgers how do I accept, I'm new to this

Comment: Click the ✔ on the answer from Ousmane.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you're getting `IndexOutOfBoundsException` because of this --> `col < 4`.

```
for(int col = 0; col < 4; col++)
```

change to this:

```
for(int col = 0; col < studentmarks[row].length; col++)
```

**side note** -  make use of the `length` property to prevent errors such as the one you've just encountered.

full solution:

```
for(int row = 0; row < studentmarks.length; row++) {
     for(int col = 0; col < studentmarks[row].length; col++) {
         System.out.print(studentmarks[row][col] + " ");
     }
     System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the error comes from exceeding the bound of the array `studentMarks` in the second for loops at the number `4` it should be `3`
A good habit to develop is to create constant variables as required with the size of each of the rows and columns, so you will not fall in such mistake.
Something like this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Array2dNightPractice{
  public static void main(String[] agrs){
    final int ROW =3, COL=3; // constant variable to determine the size of the 2d array
    int[][] studentMarks = new int[ROW][COL];
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter 9 integers");
    for(int row = 0;row<ROW;row++){ //note how I don't need to memorize and rewrite the numbers every time
        for(int col=0;col<COL;col++){
            studentMarks[row][col] = in.nextInt(); 
        }
    }
    // print the marks as matrix
    for(int row =0; row <ROW; row++) {   
        for(int col =0; col <COL; col++) {  
            System.out.print(studentMarks[row][col] + " "); 
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
  }
}
```